# Varbinary startswith query using index

Tags: sql-server, index, varbinary

I've got this tree-like key (think object OIDs--it's very similar) to store and index in a table, for which queries want to select subtrees thereof. The most straightforward way to do this on a btree is to use the tree path as the single key and descend the key with a starts-with operation to find the row blocks.

So the obvious representation is `VARBINARY(n)`*. I cannot think of a way to express starts with in a way that SQL Server can figure out to use the index thereof.

The next-most obvious is to pack the data into some `VARCHAR` with a binary collation and use a `like` operation; however I've discovered that `like @n + '%'` will never use an index, but only `like 'literal%`. Adding the `WITH INDEX` hint still scans the index in its entirety because SQL server just doesn't understand. I really don't want to think about how to escape arguments in SQL so I can build an `EXEC`. That's just madness and a security disaster waiting to happen.

Expressing this in ordinary recursive tables and querying with recursive SQL is out of the question. The recursive query will power-sink the database server.

I actually have the data in a long string of `long` variables right now and can select my serialization form. As I said, the natural form is `VARBINARY` and it really would look like `0x000000100004A010000000D0000A000`. The most common query is of the form "give me everything starting with `0x000000100004A01`" or in natural model, the first `n` values from the string of `long` values. I could write them in the form `a.b.c.d.e.f...` but the individual numbers are long and come from clicking on things on the GUI.

Roughly speaking I'm looking at a plausible form of

```
CREATE TABLE Record (
   RecordId BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
   RecordedDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
   RecordClass CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
   UserId INT NOT NULL,
   ObjectId VARBINARY(384) NOT NULL,
   RecordValue NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
   OwnerId BIGINT NULL, -- Joins to another table
   SubOwnerId BIGINT NULL, -- and yet another table
   PRIMARY KEY (RecordId)
)
CREATE INDEX name ON Record(RecordedDate);
CREATE INDEX name ON Record(OwnerId);
CREATE INDEX name ON Record(SubOwnerId);
CREATE INDEX name ON Record(ObjectId);
```

What is the best way to do a starts-with index?

<sup>*I've computed the largest possible n and it's less than 400</sup>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116386/discussion-on-question-by-joshua-varbinary-startswith-query-using-index).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as a matter of fact, starts with is not so hard to write as it would first seem. Given the initial key of 0x000000100004, obviously equals won't work and there is no starts with operation, but we can write ObjectId >= 0x000000100004 AND ObjectId < 0x000000100005.

By forcing the string of `long` values to `VARBINARY` conversion to be *big-endian* the natural form actually works correctly. We want `>= (value0 & value1 & ... & lastvalue) AND < (value0 & value1 & ... & (lastvalue + 1))`. As far as I know, the conversion to VARBINARY has to be written in application code, which is fine for me.

Comment: This is correct.  You'll need also to write a function to "increment by one" to generate second value.  But _by far_ the most natural way to do this is to store seperate columns for the components, creating a composite index on them, and making ObjectId a calculated column if needed.  Or vice-versa, adding indexed calculated columns for the components.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: Which I would have done if the maximum number of components wasn't > 60. (The number of components is variadic).

Answer (score 2):

When you use local variables SQL server doesn't take into account their values because they are unknown at the moment whe it generates execution plan for the query and it builds a plan optimized for UNKNOWN value. This is the reason why it choose scan. You can use dynamic SQL or stored procedure to make SQL Server able to optimize execution plan for particular value. For example:

```
DECLARE @LastName nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000);
SET @LastName = 'A%'
SET @sql = '
SELECT *
FROM Person.Person
WHERE LastName LIKE @LastName';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@LastName nvarchar(50)', @LastName
```

Answer (score 2):

So I'm going to go ahead and post another answer using `HIERARCHYID`  because I can. We're not going to use it because the ORM doesn't like the type. Oh well.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Record (
   RecordId BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
   RecordedDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
   RecordClass CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
   UserId INT NOT NULL,
   ObjectId HIERARCHYID NOT NULL,
   RecordValue NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
   OwnerId BIGINT NULL, -- Joins to another table
   SubOwnerId BIGINT NULL, -- and yet another table
   PRIMARY KEY (RecordId)
)
CREATE INDEX name ON Record(RecordedDate);
CREATE INDEX name ON Record(OwnerId);
CREATE INDEX name ON Record(SubOwnerId);
CREATE INDEX name ON Record(ObjectId);
```

The startswith query is not easily guessed but quite trivial:

```
SELECT RecordId, RecordedDate, RecordClass, UserId, UserId, CAST(ObjectId AS VARCHAR(800)) ObjectId, RecordValue, OwnerId, SubOwnerId
  FROM Record
 WHERE Record.ObjectId.IsDescendantOf(CAST('/id/id/id/id/' AS HIERARCHYID))
```

I tested this, and it does indeed handle our worst-case prediction of 40 bit integer components, and is at least deep enough. The optimizer knows how to use the index just fine.